# How to find delaunay triangulation facets containing the given points

Tags: python, geometry, interpolation, triangulation, delaunay

I have plotted `n` random points *(the black points)* and used delaunay triangulation, now I want to interpolate `m` random evaluation points *(the red points)* so I need to calculate which triangle the evaluation point is inside.

What is the approach for calculating the vertices of the triangle for each point?
[image]

Comment: You give a 'triangulation' tag to this question. Does it mean that triangles do not intersect? Do they form a triangulation of some object (specify it if possible)?

Comment: You can take a look at SciPy, looks like it has some implementation of the problem in question. You can start from here http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.html

Comment: I made a substantial edit to your question to make it specifically about delaunay triangulations (as it's a special subject). You're free to rollback, of course, but I feel this more appropriate :) Existing answers are still applicable, of course, but I feel that more efficient algorithms exist for delaunay triangulations.

Comment: Also, MATLAB uses Qhull for this problem, you can take a look at http://www.qhull.org/ Not python, but still, can give you an idea.

Comment: @unkulunkulu I am using [pyhull](http://pythonhosted.org/pyhull/), I have no prior knowledge in this area so all answers, references, ect are helpful.

Comment: `pyhull` is based on qhull also. Qhull has a special function for your problem, `qh_findbestfacet` http://www.qhull.org/html/qh-code.htm#findfacet Looks like pyhull doesn't have this in its interface however. Consider contributing to pyhull?

Comment: Thanks for the help @unkulunkulu I have added an answer showing the simple method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a given triangle, ABC, a point is inside the triangle if it is on the same side of line AB as point C is, on the same side of line BC as point A is, and on the same side of line AC as point B is. You can pre-optimize this check for each triangle and check them all until you find the triangle(s) it is in. See [this page](http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/) for more details.

To save computation, you can compute the minimum and maximum X and Y coordinates of the points for each triangle. If the X and Y coordinates of a point are not within the minimum and maximum values, you can immediately skip checking that triangle. The point cannot be inside it if it isn't inside the rectangle that bounds the triangle.

Comment: If the number of triangles is very large, it might pay off to build a quad-tree structure that allows for a faster search for the relevant triangles that need to be checked.

Comment: without quadtree nor bruteforce checking, there is a simple graph traversal approach that only walks along the edges of the triangles starting from any random vertex.

Comment: @WhitAngl can you provide a reference?

Comment: I upvoted Irineau's answer, which should put you in the right track. I've never coded this search myself, but I know people who did and explained the principles to me, and that was along Irineau's direction. This is a rather standard thing (e.g, look at the function TRFIND in http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f_src/tripack/tripack.f90 ). Downvoted the other answers that do not make sense, including David's (these solutions are non-standard and inefficient).

Comment: Thanks for the information, really helpful. Implemented the simple approach for now. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16000405/1066031) if your interested.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that triangles do not intersect except of common edges.

You don't want to check every triangle (or subset of them) independently. The main reason is computation errors - due to them you may get answer "inside" for more than one triangle (or zero) which may break logic of your program.

More robust way is:

1. Find closest edge to the point
2. Select one of triangles touching this edge
3. Make one check for that triangle (the point lies on the same side as the third triangle vertex)
4. If "inside" - return this triangle
5. If "outside" - return another triangle on this edge (or "nothing" if there is no other triangle)

Even if you will return wrong triangle because of computation error, there still be exactly one triangle and point will lie close enough to it to accept such mistakes.

For #1 you can use something like quad-tree as Michael Wild suggests.

Answer (score 1):

A Delaunay triangulation is in itself a search data structure. Your Delaunay triangulation implementation probably has location functions. How have you computed the Delaunay triangulation of your points?

[CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/) has an implementation of 2D and 3D triangulations. The resulting data structure is able to localize any point using a walk from a given point. See for example [that chapter of the manual](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/4.2/doc_html/cgal_manual/Triangulation_2/Chapter_main.html#Section_37.5). CGAL is a C++ library, but it has [python bindings](http://code.google.com/p/cgal-bindings/).

Comment: A Delaunay triangulation is useful for many things, not just spatial searching. So I disagree that an implementation *must* have a location function.

Comment: I am sorry for my wording. When I said: "Your Delaunay triangulation implementation must have location functions", the "must" should have been a "may".

Answer (score 1):

This simple example triangulates 10 random points, a further 3 random points are generated and if they fall inside a triangle the vertices are given:

```
import numpy as np
from pyhull.delaunay import DelaunayTri

def sign(a,b,c):
    return (a[0]-c[0])*(b[1]-c[1])-(b[0]-c[0])*(a[1]-c[1])

def findfacet(p,simplice):
    c,b,a = simplice.coords
    b1 = sign(p,a,b) < 0.0
    b2 = sign(p,b,c) < 0.0
    b3 = sign(p,c,a) < 0.0
    return b1 == b2 == b3

data = np.random.randn(10, 2)
dtri = DelaunayTri(data)

interpolate = np.random.randn(3, 2)

for point in interpolate:
    for triangle in dtri.simplices:
        if findfacet(point,triangle):
            print "Point",point,"inside",triangle.coords
        break
```

Using `matplotlib` to visualize *(code omitted)*:

[image]

The dotted cyan lines now connect the points to interpolate with the vertices of triangle it lays within. The black lines are the convex hull, and the solid cyan lines are the delaunay triangulation.